# Не могу получить доступ к библиотеки SQlite

Tags: c#, sqlite

Вопрос пересоздал, так как там другой аккаунт, от которого я забыл пароль и почту :D
Извините

Что стоит:

[image: Что стоит]

Ошибка

[image: Ошибка]

В этом коде не работает

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Data.SQLite;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.IO;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.Sql;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Data.SqlTypes;


namespace dpapi
{
class Program
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string fileDb = @"C:\Users\noname\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\User Data\Default\Login Data"; // Путь к логин данным
        string connectionString = $"Data Source = {fileDb}";
        string fileName = @"C:\Windows\Temp\output.txt"; // Выходной файл с паролями
        StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(fileName, false, Encoding.UTF8);
        string dbWay = "Login Data";
        string db_fields = "logins"; // база паролей SQLITE
        byte[] entropy = null;
        string description;

        DataTable db = new DataTable();
        string sql = $"SELECT * FROM {db_fields}";
        using (SQLiteConnection connection = new SQLiteConnection(connectionString))
        {
            SQLiteCommand command = new SQLiteCommand(sql, connection);
            SQLiteDataAdapter adapter = new SQLiteDataAdapter(command);
            adapter.Fill(db);
        }

        int rows = db.Rows.Count;
        Console.WriteLine($"Всего записей: {rows}");

        for (int i = 0; i < rows; i++)
        {
            string url = db.Rows[i][1].ToString();
            string login = db.Rows[i][3].ToString();
            byte[] byteArray = (byte[])db.Rows[i][5];
            byte[] decrypted = DPAPI.Decrypt(byteArray, entropy, out description);
            string password = new UTF8Encoding(true).GetString(decrypted);
            sw.WriteLine("----------------------------");
            sw.WriteLine($"Номер: {i}");
            sw.WriteLine($"Сайт: {url}");
            sw.WriteLine($"Логин: {login}");
            sw.WriteLine($"Пароль: {password}");
        }
        sw.Close();
    }
}
public class DPAPI
{
    // Wrapper for DPAPI CryptProtectData function.
    [DllImport("crypt32.dll",
                SetLastError = true,
                CharSet = System.Runtime.InteropServices.CharSet.Auto)]
    private static extern
        bool CryptProtectData(ref DATA_BLOB pPlainText,
                                    string szDescription,
                                ref DATA_BLOB pEntropy,
                                    IntPtr pReserved,
                                ref CRYPTPROTECT_PROMPTSTRUCT pPrompt,
                                    int dwFlags,
                                ref DATA_BLOB pCipherText);

    // Wrapper for DPAPI CryptUnprotectData function.
    [DllImport("crypt32.dll",
                SetLastError = true,
                CharSet = System.Runtime.InteropServices.CharSet.Auto)]
    private static extern
        bool CryptUnprotectData(ref DATA_BLOB pCipherText,
                                ref string pszDescription,
                                ref DATA_BLOB pEntropy,
                                    IntPtr pReserved,
                                ref CRYPTPROTECT_PROMPTSTRUCT pPrompt,
                                    int dwFlags,
                                ref DATA_BLOB pPlainText);

    // BLOB structure used to pass data to DPAPI functions.
    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, CharSet = CharSet.Unicode)]
    internal struct DATA_BLOB
    {
        public int cbData;
        public IntPtr pbData;
    }

    // Prompt structure to be used for required parameters.
    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, CharSet = CharSet.Unicode)]
    internal struct CRYPTPROTECT_PROMPTSTRUCT
    {
        public int cbSize;
        public int dwPromptFlags;
        public IntPtr hwndApp;
        public string szPrompt;
    }

    // Wrapper for the NULL handle or pointer.
    static private IntPtr NullPtr = ((IntPtr)((int)(0)));

    // DPAPI key initialization flags.
    private const int CRYPTPROTECT_UI_FORBIDDEN = 0x1;
    private const int CRYPTPROTECT_LOCAL_MACHINE = 0x4;

    /// <summary>
    /// Initializes empty prompt structure.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="ps">
    /// Prompt parameter (which we do not actually need).
    /// </param>
    private static void InitPrompt(ref CRYPTPROTECT_PROMPTSTRUCT ps)
    {
        ps.cbSize = Marshal.SizeOf(
                                  typeof(CRYPTPROTECT_PROMPTSTRUCT));
        ps.dwPromptFlags = 0;
        ps.hwndApp = NullPtr;
        ps.szPrompt = null;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Initializes a BLOB structure from a byte array.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="data">
    /// Original data in a byte array format.
    /// </param>
    /// <param name="blob">
    /// Returned blob structure.
    /// </param>
    private static void InitBLOB(byte[] data, ref DATA_BLOB blob)
    {
        // Use empty array for null parameter.
        if (data == null)
            data = new byte[0];

        // Allocate memory for the BLOB data.
        blob.pbData = Marshal.AllocHGlobal(data.Length);

        // Make sure that memory allocation was successful.
        if (blob.pbData == IntPtr.Zero)
            throw new Exception(
                "Unable to allocate data buffer for BLOB structure.");

        // Specify number of bytes in the BLOB.
        blob.cbData = data.Length;

        // Copy data from original source to the BLOB structure.
        Marshal.Copy(data, 0, blob.pbData, data.Length);
    }

    // Flag indicating the type of key. DPAPI terminology refers to
    // key types as user store or machine store.
    public enum KeyType { UserKey = 1, MachineKey };

    // It is reasonable to set default key type to user key.
    private static KeyType defaultKeyType = KeyType.UserKey;

    /// <summary>
    /// Calls DPAPI CryptProtectData function to encrypt a plaintext
    /// string value with a user-specific key. This function does not
    /// specify data description and additional entropy.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="plainText">
    /// Plaintext data to be encrypted.
    /// </param>
    /// <returns>
    /// Encrypted value in a base64-encoded format.
    /// </returns>
    public static string Encrypt(string plainText)
    {
        return Encrypt(defaultKeyType, plainText, String.Empty,
                        String.Empty);
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Calls DPAPI CryptProtectData function to encrypt a plaintext
    /// string value. This function does not specify data description
    /// and additional entropy.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="keyType">
    /// Defines type of encryption key to use. When user key is
    /// specified, any application running under the same user account
    /// as the one making this call, will be able to decrypt data.
    /// Machine key will allow any application running on the same
    /// computer where data were encrypted to perform decryption.
    /// Note: If optional entropy is specifed, it will be required
    /// for decryption.
    /// </param>
    /// <param name="plainText">
    /// Plaintext data to be encrypted.
    /// </param>
    /// <returns>
    /// Encrypted value in a base64-encoded format.
    /// </returns>
    public static string Encrypt(KeyType keyType, string plainText)
    {
        return Encrypt(keyType, plainText, String.Empty,
                        String.Empty);
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Calls DPAPI CryptProtectData function to encrypt a plaintext
    /// string value. This function does not specify data description.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="keyType">
    /// Defines type of encryption key to use. When user key is
    /// specified, any application running under the same user account
    /// as the one making this call, will be able to decrypt data.
    /// Machine key will allow any application running on the same
    /// computer where data were encrypted to perform decryption.
    /// Note: If optional entropy is specifed, it will be required
    /// for decryption.
    /// </param>
    /// <param name="plainText">
    /// Plaintext data to be encrypted.
    /// </param>
    /// <param name="entropy">
    /// Optional entropy which - if specified - will be required to
    /// perform decryption.
    /// </param>
    /// <returns>
    /// Encrypted value in a base64-encoded format.
    /// </returns>
    public static string Encrypt(KeyType keyType,
                                 string plainText,
                                 string entropy)
    {
        return Encrypt(keyType, plainText, entropy, String.Empty);
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Calls DPAPI CryptProtectData function to encrypt a plaintext
    /// string value.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="keyType">
    /// Defines type of encryption key to use. When user key is
    /// specified, any application running under the same user account
    /// as the one making this call, will be able to decrypt data.
    /// Machine key will allow any application running on the same
    /// computer where data were encrypted to perform decryption.
    /// Note: If optional entropy is specifed, it will be required
    /// for decryption.
    /// </param>
    /// <param name="plainText">
    /// Plaintext data to be encrypted.
    /// </param>
    /// <param name="entropy">
    /// Optional entropy which - if specified - will be required to
    /// perform decryption.
    /// </param>
    /// <param name="description">
    /// Optional description of data to be encrypted. If this value is
    /// specified, it will be stored along with encrypted data and
    /// returned as a separate value during decryption.
    /// </param>
    /// <returns>
    /// Encrypted value in a base64-encoded format.
    /// </returns>
    public static string Encrypt(KeyType keyType,
                                 string plainText,
                                 string entropy,
                                 string description)
    {
        // Make sure that parameters are valid.
        if (plainText == null) plainText = String.Empty;
        if (entropy == null) entropy = String.Empty;

        // Call encryption routine and convert returned bytes into
        // a base64-encoded value.
        return Convert.ToBase64String(
                Encrypt(keyType,
                        Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(plainText),
                        Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(entropy),
                        description));
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Calls DPAPI CryptProtectData function to encrypt an array of
    /// plaintext bytes.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="keyType">
    /// Defines type of encryption key to use. When user key is
    /// specified, any application running under the same user account
    /// as the one making this call, will be able to decrypt data.
    /// Machine key will allow any application running on the same
    /// computer where data were encrypted to perform decryption.
    /// Note: If optional entropy is specifed, it will be required
    /// for decryption.
    /// </param>
    /// <param name="plainTextBytes">
    /// Plaintext data to be encrypted.
    /// </param>
    /// <param name="entropyBytes">
    /// Optional entropy which - if specified - will be required to
    /// perform decryption.
    /// </param>
    /// <param name="description">
    /// Optional description of data to be encrypted. If this value is
    /// specified, it will be stored along with encrypted data and
    /// returned as a separate value during decryption.
    /// </param>
    /// <returns>
    /// Encrypted value.
    /// </returns>
    public static byte[] Encrypt(KeyType keyType,
                                 byte[] plainTextBytes,
                                 byte[] entropyBytes,
                                 string description)
    {
        // Make sure that parameters are valid.
        if (plainTextBytes == null) plainTextBytes = new byte[0];
        if (entropyBytes == null) entropyBytes = new byte[0];
        if (description == null) description = String.Empty;

        // Create BLOBs to hold data.
        DATA_BLOB plainTextBlob = new DATA_BLOB();
        DATA_BLOB cipherTextBlob = new DATA_BLOB();
        DATA_BLOB entropyBlob = new DATA_BLOB();

        // We only need prompt structure because it is a required
        // parameter.
        CRYPTPROTECT_PROMPTSTRUCT prompt =
                                  new CRYPTPROTECT_PROMPTSTRUCT();
        InitPrompt(ref prompt);

        try
        {
            // Convert plaintext bytes into a BLOB structure.
            try
            {
                InitBLOB(plainTextBytes, ref plainTextBlob);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                throw new Exception(
                    "Cannot initialize plaintext BLOB.", ex);
            }

            // Convert entropy bytes into a BLOB structure.
            try
            {
                InitBLOB(entropyBytes, ref entropyBlob);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                throw new Exception(
                    "Cannot initialize entropy BLOB.", ex);
            }

            // Disable any types of UI.
            int flags = CRYPTPROTECT_UI_FORBIDDEN;

            // When using machine-specific key, set up machine flag.
            if (keyType == KeyType.MachineKey)
                flags |= CRYPTPROTECT_LOCAL_MACHINE;

            // Call DPAPI to encrypt data.
            bool success = CryptProtectData(ref plainTextBlob,
                                                description,
                                            ref entropyBlob,
                                                IntPtr.Zero,
                                            ref prompt,
                                                flags,
                                            ref cipherTextBlob);
            // Check the result.
            if (!success)
            {
                // If operation failed, retrieve last Win32 error.
                int errCode = Marshal.GetLastWin32Error();

                // Win32Exception will contain error message corresponding
                // to the Windows error code.
                throw new Exception(
                    "CryptProtectData failed.", new Win32Exception(errCode));
            }

            // Allocate memory to hold ciphertext.
            byte[] cipherTextBytes = new byte[cipherTextBlob.cbData];

            // Copy ciphertext from the BLOB to a byte array.
            Marshal.Copy(cipherTextBlob.pbData,
                            cipherTextBytes,
                            0,
                            cipherTextBlob.cbData);

            // Return the result.
            return cipherTextBytes;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw new Exception("DPAPI was unable to encrypt data.", ex);
        }
        // Free all memory allocated for BLOBs.
        finally
        {
            if (plainTextBlob.pbData != IntPtr.Zero)
                Marshal.FreeHGlobal(plainTextBlob.pbData);

            if (cipherTextBlob.pbData != IntPtr.Zero)
                Marshal.FreeHGlobal(cipherTextBlob.pbData);

            if (entropyBlob.pbData != IntPtr.Zero)
                Marshal.FreeHGlobal(entropyBlob.pbData);
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Calls DPAPI CryptUnprotectData to decrypt ciphertext bytes.
    /// This function does not use additional entropy and does not
    /// return data description.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="cipherText">
    /// Encrypted data formatted as a base64-encoded string.
    /// </param>
    /// <returns>
    /// Decrypted data returned as a UTF-8 string.
    /// </returns>
    /// <remarks>
    /// When decrypting data, it is not necessary to specify which
    /// type of encryption key to use: user-specific or
    /// machine-specific; DPAPI will figure it out by looking at
    /// the signature of encrypted data.
    /// </remarks>
    public static string Decrypt(string cipherText)
    {
        string description;

        return Decrypt(cipherText, String.Empty, out description);
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Calls DPAPI CryptUnprotectData to decrypt ciphertext bytes.
    /// This function does not use additional entropy.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="cipherText">
    /// Encrypted data formatted as a base64-encoded string.
    /// </param>
    /// <param name="description">
    /// Returned description of data specified during encryption.
    /// </param>
    /// <returns>
    /// Decrypted data returned as a UTF-8 string.
    /// </returns>
    /// <remarks>
    /// When decrypting data, it is not necessary to specify which
    /// type of encryption key to use: user-specific or
    /// machine-specific; DPAPI will figure it out by looking at
    /// the signature of encrypted data.
    /// </remarks>
    public static string Decrypt(string cipherText,
                                 out string description)
    {
        return Decrypt(cipherText, String.Empty, out description);
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Calls DPAPI CryptUnprotectData to decrypt ciphertext bytes.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="cipherText">
    /// Encrypted data formatted as a base64-encoded string.
    /// </param>
    /// <param name="entropy">
    /// Optional entropy, which is required if it was specified during
    /// encryption.
    /// </param>
    /// <param name="description">
    /// Returned description of data specified during encryption.
    /// </param>
    /// <returns>
    /// Decrypted data returned as a UTF-8 string.
    /// </returns>
    /// <remarks>
    /// When decrypting data, it is not necessary to specify which
    /// type of encryption key to use: user-specific or
    /// machine-specific; DPAPI will figure it out by looking at
    /// the signature of encrypted data.
    /// </remarks>
    public static string Decrypt(string cipherText,
                                     string entropy,
                                 out string description)
    {
        // Make sure that parameters are valid.
        if (entropy == null) entropy = String.Empty;

        return Encoding.UTF8.GetString(
                    Decrypt(Convert.FromBase64String(cipherText),
                                Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(entropy),
                            out description));
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Calls DPAPI CryptUnprotectData to decrypt ciphertext bytes.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="cipherTextBytes">
    /// Encrypted data.
    /// </param>
    /// <param name="entropyBytes">
    /// Optional entropy, which is required if it was specified during
    /// encryption.
    /// </param>
    /// <param name="description">
    /// Returned description of data specified during encryption.
    /// </param>
    /// <returns>
    /// Decrypted data bytes.
    /// </returns>
    /// <remarks>
    /// When decrypting data, it is not necessary to specify which
    /// type of encryption key to use: user-specific or
    /// machine-specific; DPAPI will figure it out by looking at
    /// the signature of encrypted data.
    /// </remarks>
    public static byte[] Decrypt(byte[] cipherTextBytes,
                                     byte[] entropyBytes,
                                 out string description)
    {
        // Create BLOBs to hold data.
        DATA_BLOB plainTextBlob = new DATA_BLOB();
        DATA_BLOB cipherTextBlob = new DATA_BLOB();
        DATA_BLOB entropyBlob = new DATA_BLOB();

        // We only need prompt structure because it is a required
        // parameter.
        CRYPTPROTECT_PROMPTSTRUCT prompt =
                                  new CRYPTPROTECT_PROMPTSTRUCT();
        InitPrompt(ref prompt);

        // Initialize description string.
        description = String.Empty;

        try
        {
            // Convert ciphertext bytes into a BLOB structure.
            try
            {
                InitBLOB(cipherTextBytes, ref cipherTextBlob);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                throw new Exception(
                    "Cannot initialize ciphertext BLOB.", ex);
            }

            // Convert entropy bytes into a BLOB structure.
            try
            {
                InitBLOB(entropyBytes, ref entropyBlob);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                throw new Exception(
                    "Cannot initialize entropy BLOB.", ex);
            }

            // Disable any types of UI. CryptUnprotectData does not
            // mention CRYPTPROTECT_LOCAL_MACHINE flag in the list of
            // supported flags so we will not set it up.
            int flags = CRYPTPROTECT_UI_FORBIDDEN;

            // Call DPAPI to decrypt data.
            bool success = CryptUnprotectData(ref cipherTextBlob,
                                              ref description,
                                              ref entropyBlob,
                                                  IntPtr.Zero,
                                              ref prompt,
                                                  flags,
                                              ref plainTextBlob);

            // Check the result.
            if (!success)
            {
                // If operation failed, retrieve last Win32 error.
                int errCode = Marshal.GetLastWin32Error();

                // Win32Exception will contain error message corresponding
                // to the Windows error code.
                throw new Exception(
                    "CryptUnprotectData failed.", new Win32Exception(errCode));
            }

            // Allocate memory to hold plaintext.
            byte[] plainTextBytes = new byte[plainTextBlob.cbData];

            // Copy ciphertext from the BLOB to a byte array.
            Marshal.Copy(plainTextBlob.pbData,
                         plainTextBytes,
                         0,
                         plainTextBlob.cbData);

            // Return the result.
            return plainTextBytes;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw new Exception("DPAPI was unable to decrypt data.", ex);
        }
        // Free all memory allocated for BLOBs.
        finally
        {
            if (plainTextBlob.pbData != IntPtr.Zero)
                Marshal.FreeHGlobal(plainTextBlob.pbData);

            if (cipherTextBlob.pbData != IntPtr.Zero)
                Marshal.FreeHGlobal(cipherTextBlob.pbData);

            if (entropyBlob.pbData != IntPtr.Zero)
                Marshal.FreeHGlobal(entropyBlob.pbData);
        }
    }
}
```

}

Отсюда класс [DPAPI]: http://www.obviex.com/samples/dpapi.aspx